# How do you include fields values in MDT packages?

Tags: package, change-set, custom-metadata

I have created a Custom Metadata Type, created some records ("Manage" button) and included it into a Change Set. When I deploy the CS, I only get the structure of the MDT not its values... I though it was the point?

Not surprisingly, when taking a look at the package from an Ant perspective, I can see that my package only contains the object description and nothing about the records I have created... What needs to be added to be able to deploy it all (MDT + records) in one go?

Comment: Did you add the specific metadata records to the package?

Comment: Sorry @Sebastian, missed your question. Thanks and, yes, you were indeed pointing at the right root cause / see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deploy custom metadata records in changesets, but you have to add them to the changeset (which is different from just adding the type). In the "Component Type" dropdown, look for the name of your custom metadata type (In Summer 15, the Api Name; in Winter 16 it's the label).

Every custom metadata will itself appear in the drop down .

[image]

In this Default Briefing Source Field Mapping is my Custom metadata label.

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed this information somehow in my research... :)